# Angular Material TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

After installing angular material and adding the components in app.module, I'm getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out, I was importing the components, NOT the modules.
[image]

> Should not import the components.

[image]

> Should import the modules.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you were having until I found your question!  Yes.  You are correct about importing the module.  Importing non-modules will cause Angular to fail in runtime.  The function `registerNgModuleType(ngModuleType)`, which is the one causing the failure, is meant for modules only, and it is run on each import. So anything without an ngModuleType is not a module, and cannot be properly passed through this function.